# setDividerLocation in JSplitPane

Tags: java, jframe, jsplitpane

I have one JFrame containing Splitpane. By default, the right pane is greater than left pane, but I need left pane to be larger than the right pane. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, left, right);
split.setDividerLocation(500);
frame.getContentPane().add(split);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setDividerLocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation(double)) method that takes a `double` as a ratio value (between 0.0 and 1.0) :

Here, the left pane will take 60% of the total width :

```
split.setDividerLocation(0.6);
```

It seems that the splitpane may have to be already visible for this to work :

> If the split pane is not correctly realized and on screen, this
>   method will have no effect (new divider location will become (current
>   size * proportionalLocation) which is 0).

So, call `setDividerLocation` only once your frame's content has been added, and the frame has been made visible.